# How to write a query with NULL for missing values

Tags: mysql, sql

Below, I have 2 tables.  I want to write a query that will return each `NAME` and the corresponding `UIN` value.  If there is no `UIN` value, I want to return `NULL` for that entry instead

[image]

For example, 2 entries should be like this for Samanta should be:

`Bob 49638-001`

`Samantha NULL`

I've tried `SELECT NAME JOIN EMPLOYEE_UIN.UIN INSERT "NULL" WHERE UIN = NULL` but no luck.  I'm a beginner with SQL and I couldn't find a similar example on SO about this.

Comment: A decent, introductory book or tutorial would pay dividends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a LEFT JOIN, this will display all elements on the left table (Employee) and the properties of the right table (Employee_unit) only when they matches the condition criteria (this case `E1.id = E2.id`). This means that when the condition is not a match, it will display NULL values for all the references to properties of the right table (on this case the E2.UNI). That is exactly what you want.

```
Select E.Name,  E2.UIN
FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ID;
```

For more insights on using joins see [MySQL join made easy.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: If you can add some details as to how a LEFT JOIN solves the OPs problem that would be a great improvement to your answer.

Comment: How about the NULL placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

use COALESCE with left join to solve your problem

```
Select E.Name,  COALESCE(E2.UIN,"NULL")
    FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_UNIT E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ID;
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely useful on Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer and explain why it works and how it solves the OP's problem. Thanks.